# running scripts on ssh remotely

Tags: mysql, database, ssh

I have a python script and a file (both on ssh) to be inserted to a db (mysql) using the python script. My file has 53,000,000 rows to be submitted to the db. This submission takes a very long time. Is there anyway in which I can run the script so that even if I exit ssh the script continues running?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `screen` or `tmux`. Both commands allow you to have detached user session. You can reconnect at any time to this session. 
You only need to start `screen` and run your scripts there. After that you can push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and than <kbd>d</kbd> and your session will be detached. 
To restore your session you need to run `screen -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have it handled in a jenkins pipline, setup a job in jenkins to run the script.